# Beamer talk with two title slides

Tags: beamer, titles

I would like to create a Beamer presentation where the first two PDF pages are two title slides that are identical in every respect apart from the fact that one contains the real title of the talk and the other contains a catchy/humorous alternative title.

Is there a way to achieve this within the apparatus of the `\titlepage` command, or do I need to manually code the layout of the slide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next worked for me. I've used `\title[Official Title]{Second title}` in order to respect the official title in headings or footers.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Official title}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\title[Official Title]{Second title}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```